# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found-- difficulty webscraping

Tags: web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to webscrape a table and this is the code I am using. I have tried a variety of things, but I am new to Python and they are not working. Any one have ideas? In your answer could you please include where that portion of the code would be inserted.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup('https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/saisontransfers/statistik?land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&transferfenster=&saison-id=2020&plus=1')
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\PycharmProjects\tablepractice\tablescrape.py", line 11, in <module>
soup = make_soup('https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/saisontransfers/statistik?land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&transferfenster=&saison-id=2020&plus=1')
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\PycharmProjects\tablepractice\tablescrape.py", line 7, in make_soup
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\GBEM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

To get correct response from server, specify `User-Agent` HTTP header:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

def make_soup(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')

soup = make_soup('https://www.transfermarkt.com/transfers/saisontransfers/statistik?land_id=0&ausrichtung=&spielerposition_id=&altersklasse=&leihe=&transferfenster=&saison-id=2020&plus=1')
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

..and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved the problem